# How to insert data into table in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I use this code in my model,

```
public function registration(){
$name = 'Foo';
$city = 'Bar';

$this->User->save( 
    array(
        'name' => $name,
        'city' => $city
        )
    );
}
```

But while inserting get a fatal error

```
"Error: Call to a member function save() on a non-object
 File: C:\xampp\htdocs\blogs\app\Model\User.php"
```

How to insert it ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are already in the `User` model. Just do the following:

```
$this->save( 
    array(
        'name' => $name,
        'city' => $city
        )
    );
}
```